# SQL “Row values” syntax in WHERE clause with JPA Criteria API

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Is it possible with Criteria API to generate **WHERE** clause with "row values"?

Like [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html)

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (column1,column2) < (1,1);
```

**Use case**: let's say we can receive from a client a parameter list of variable length.

If client send one param `A` then I want to generate e.g `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1 < ?`

If client send two params `A` and `B` then `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1 < ? OR ((c1 = ?) AND (c2 < ?))`

and so on up to N parameters.

Definitely, I can implement this logic using Criteria's `and`, `or` etc. methods, but with "row values" syntax an implementation would be much simpler.

So, my question is whether there is some method(s) in Criteria API which helps to build SQL with row values syntax

Comment: The Criteria API certainly allows having a `WHERE` clause with multiple restrictions.  I don't see the point of your question, since Criteria syntax doesn't really look like SQL code, but rather Java code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I updated the question with an example. If it makes it clearer

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for here.  You can already do what you want with the current Criteria API, which, again, exposes a very different interface than the raw SQL code you have in mind.  Maybe show us your current Criteria Java code and then point out what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Stanislau I came in an exact same problem. I want to implement seek for next page. Have you find a solution?

Comment: @srnjak, unfortunately no. I'm using, as mentioned in the question, just a bunch of and/or clauses